# Adding Multiple raster datasets to mosaic dataset (for temporal change) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, time, mosaic-dataset

I have a number of raster datasets containing lake water temperature data. I am looking to make these time enabled as to be able to scroll through them. I have converted them to .TIFF format and have tried using the "Add Raster to Mosaic Dataset" Tool. However, I am told to find my .TIFF files while "workspace" is selected. I cannot find these files unless I change "workspace" to "raster dataset"

Am I missing a particular setting in the tool? OR Am I missing a particular step?

Comment: I think this question needs more details of the precise steps you performed e.g. all parameter values used for all tools used.